# What are list of the words describing pecuilar characteristic of animals and birds in English language?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for the list of the words which describes various peculiarity of animals or birds.

E.g. A **wise** Owl. We say this because we always associate Owl in stories, cartoon, movies etc. as wise.

An other example is of Crow. We always consider Crow to be **clever**.

Can you please provide a list of words describing particular peculiarity of animals and birds?

Comment: Here is a [List of Animal Similes](https://owlcation.com/academia/animal-similes) and [here is another](https://www.dogcatplace.com/wildanimals/all-animal-similes) but I think the question is off-topic as this was basic research that is easy to find.

Comment: There are a great many ways to refer to groups of animals collectively, such as a pride of lions or an exultation of larks. Is that what you mean?? There are also formal adjectives for many, used as metaphor: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/50-words-that-describe-animals-including-humans/

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Questions asking for lists of things aren't a good fit for our format, because they can't be completely answered with one reasonable length answer unless we're just pointing to other compiled lists on the web. This seems like a resource request, and we usually handle those on [meta] since they're out of scope on the main site, so I'm going to go ahead an transfer it there.